# Real-Time Live Video Processing in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis

Are there solutions in AWS for handling large quantities of real-time video processing?

For example:

`client (input/output) <-> Video is processed in real-time <-> client (input/output)`

Ideally, we would be processing large amounts of data (~400ms latency) for a large number of client devices.

After piping the data through Kinesis and into Firehose, are their options to handle this sort of processing?

(I know Lambda may not work due to its 5 or so minute lifetime)

Comment: Assume you looked at services like https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/. I would guess most people write to S3 bucket then on put trigger a event either to SNS to SQS or fire a Lambda function. Rather than piping through Kinesis is there a reason to go through there ?

Comment: I looked into it. I also looked into Rekognition. The main issue is that any processing must be done in under 400ms. It limits the use cases we're able to satisfy, but since its real-time, we have to adhere to that limitation most importantly.

Comment: What do you mean by “processing”?

Comment: So for example, a real time conversation over video whereby I decide to throw a hat onto you. Or do echo/noise reduction on the audio stream.... Stuff like that.